# Changing document.width like devtools does?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, responsive-design

In the Developer Tools there is a device-metrics setting that allows you to change the viewport in the browser to simulate different screen sizes. It appears to change the document.width property to do so. This is read-only in JS. Is there any way to achieve the same thing in an extension? I currently have to resize the browser window which isn't very elegant.

Comment: You can make it possible with content scripts in a Chrome extension.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the [Resolution Test](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/resolution-test/idhfcdbheobinplaamokffboaccidbal) plugin.